# Как оптимизировать программу и уменьшить время ее выполнения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

**Есть задача по программированию в рамках курса "Алгоритмы и структуры данных"**

Задача про обход графа

Реализуйте обход графа в ширину и глубину.
Вершины упорядочены в лексикографическом порядке.

Формат входных данных

Первая строка стандартного потока ввода данных имеет формат "[graph_type] [start_vertex] [search_type]",

где "[graph_type]" - тип графа, ориентированный ('d') или неориентированный ('u');

"[start_vertex]" - идентификатор вершины, с которой начинать обход графа;

"[search_type]" - тип обхода, в ширину ('b') или в глубину ('d').

Каждая последующая строка содержит ребро, которая представляет собой идентификаторы начальной и конечной вершины, разделенные пробелом.

Формат результата

Результат работы программы выводится в стандартный поток вывода.
Идентификаторы посещенных вершин выводятся по одному в строке в порядке обхода.

**Как можно оптимизировать следующий код на C++, чтобы программа работала намного быстрее?**

*P/s Один из тестов - это входные данные с более 100 текстовыми строками, что выполняется сейчас больше чем за 10 секунд (а 10 секунд - time limit)*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <time.h>
#include <set>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::multimap;
using std::set;

int main() {
//    time_t start, end;
//    time(&start);
//
    string prom;

    char graph_type;
    string start_vertex;
    char search_type;

    bool error = false; //любая непонятная ситуация завершает работу программы
    bool initGraph = false; //считана ли строка с характеристиками графа

    set<string> arrayOfVertexes; //вектор вершин
    multimap<string, string> edges; //ребра графа

    while(!cin.eof()) {
        std::getline(cin, prom);
        if(!prom.empty()) {
            if(!initGraph && !error) {
                graph_type = prom[0];

                int first_ = prom.find_first_of(" \f\n\r\t\v", 0);
                int last_ = prom.find_first_of(" \f\n\r\t\v", first_ + 1);

                if (first_ != string::npos && last_ != string::npos)
                    start_vertex = prom.substr(first_ + 1, last_ - first_ - 1);

                first_ = last_;

                search_type = prom[prom.size() - 1];

//                cout << graph_type << " " << start_vertex << " " << search_type << endl;

                error = true;

                if((graph_type == 'd' || graph_type == 'u') && (search_type == 'b' || search_type == 'd')) {
                    error = false;
                    initGraph = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if(initGraph && !error) {
                string f_vertex;
                string s_vertex;
                bool errorV = true;

                int f = prom.find_first_of(",\"'-0123456789=\\_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
                int l = prom.find_first_not_of(",\"'-0123456789=\\_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", f);

                if(f != string::npos && l != string::npos) {
                    errorV = false;
                    string vertex = prom.substr(f, l - f);
                    f_vertex = vertex;

                    arrayOfVertexes.insert(vertex);
                }
                else
                    errorV = true;

                if(!errorV) {
                    f = prom.find_first_of(",\"'-0123456789=\\_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", l);
                    l = prom.find_first_not_of(",\"'-0123456789=\\_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", f + 1);

                    if(f != string::npos) {
                        errorV = false;
                        string vertex = prom.substr(f, l - f);
                        s_vertex = vertex;

                        arrayOfVertexes.insert(vertex);
                    }
                    else
                        errorV = true;

                    if(!errorV) {
                        if (l == prom.size() - 1) {
                            errorV = true;
                            arrayOfVertexes.erase(f_vertex);
                            arrayOfVertexes.erase(s_vertex);
                        }
                        else {
                            edges.insert(std::pair<string, string>(f_vertex, s_vertex));
                            errorV = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vector<vector<int> > arraySmej(arrayOfVertexes.size(), vector<int>(arrayOfVertexes.size(), 0)); //матрица смежности


    if (!arrayOfVertexes.empty())
        error = false;

    set<string>::iterator it = arrayOfVertexes.find(start_vertex);
    if (it == arrayOfVertexes.end())
        error = true;

    if(!error) {
        bool orient = false;

        if (graph_type == 'd')
            orient = true;

        for(multimap<string, string>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++) {
            int f = std::distance(arrayOfVertexes.begin(), arrayOfVertexes.find(it->first));
            int l = std::distance(arrayOfVertexes.begin(), arrayOfVertexes.find(it->second));
            if (it->first != it->second) {
                arraySmej[f][l] = 1;
                if (!orient) {
                    arraySmej[l][f] = 1;
                }
            }
        }


        if (search_type == 'b') {
            std::queue<int> Queue;
            vector<int> nodes(arrayOfVertexes.size(), 0);

            int posStart = std::distance(arrayOfVertexes.begin(), arrayOfVertexes.find(start_vertex));

            Queue.push(posStart);
            while (!Queue.empty()) {
                int node = Queue.front();
                Queue.pop();
                nodes[node] = 2;
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfVertexes.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (arraySmej[node][j] == 1 && nodes[j] == 0)
                    {
                        Queue.push(j);
                        nodes[j] = 1;
                    }
                }

                std::set<string>::iterator it = arrayOfVertexes.begin();
                std::advance(it, node);
                cout << *it << endl;
            }
        }

        if (search_type == 'd') {
            std::stack<int> Stack;
            vector<int> nodes(arrayOfVertexes.size(), 0);

            int posStart = std::distance(arrayOfVertexes.begin(), arrayOfVertexes.find(start_vertex));

            Stack.push(posStart);

            while (!Stack.empty()) {
                int node = Stack.top();
                Stack.pop();
                if (nodes[node] == 2) continue;
                nodes[node] = 2;
                for (int j = arrayOfVertexes.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (arraySmej[node][j] == 1 && nodes[j] != 2)
                    {
                        Stack.push(j);
                        nodes[j] = 1;
                    }
                }

                std::set<string>::iterator it = arrayOfVertexes.begin();
                std::advance(it, node);
                cout << *it << endl;
            }
        }
    }

//    time(&end);
//
//    cout << "Время выполнения: " << difftime(end, start) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему то мне кажется, что оптимизировать это не стоит. Нужно написать заново  и на принципах ООП:  И нужно понимать  роли обьектов, а не просто создавать обьекты всех типов стандартных контейнеров...

Comment: Если нужно оптимизировать код, то смотрите в сторону уменшения количества вложенных циклов и ветвлений. Хотя начать стоит с компиляции с O2.

Comment: я бы для начала попытался упростить ввод/вывод. Возможно что-то подобное вам поможет https://ideone.com/eIbkNs.

Comment: вы сами не путаетесь в этой мешанине? Попробуйте разбить ваш кодна небольшие функции, одна функция на считывание графа, одна на DFS, одна на BFS, одна на запись результатов. Разделив код на функции, вы уменьшите сложность вашего текста и сможете говорить предметно, мол, вот BFS медленный или DFS или считывание - то есть сузите вашу прблему.